# Number format of plot legend

Tags: plotting, legending, number-representation, charts, plot-themes

How can I change format of numbers for bar legends.
I would like to show numbers without digits after the decimal point.

[image: bar legend]

> 

```
ListContourPlot[data,
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {m, M}},
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {lb, ub}}, LegendMarkerSize -> 200, 
    LegendLabel -> Placed["\[CapitalOmega].m", Bottom], 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, 14}, , LegendFunction -> f], Right],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ContourShading -> Hue /@ Reverse[Subdivide[.67, nc - 1]],
 ImageSize -> 1200,
 ContourStyle -> None,
 Contours -> Table[lb*(ub/lb)^(n/nc), {n, 1, nc - 1}],
 PlotRangePadding -> None,
 FrameLabel -> {"Distance (m)", "Depth (m)", None, "Elevation (ft)"},
 LabelStyle -> {Black, 14},
 FrameTicks -> {{All, 
    Table[{-3.05 n, 262 - 10 n}, {n, 0, 9, 1}]}, {All, None}},
 AspectRatio -> .2
 ]
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: And what are `data`?  and `lb`?  and `ub`?  and `n`?  and `nc`? and `f`?  Especially `f`?

Comment: f is what you wrote but did not work.

Comment: m = Min[data[[All, 3]]]
M = Max[data[[All, 3]]]
lb = 15
ub = 300
nc = 16;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the undocumented option `"LabelingFunction"` in your `BarLegend`:

```
bl1 = BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {18.1234, 23.124}}, 5];
bl2 = BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {18.1234, 23.124}}, 5, 
   "LabelingFunction" -> (Round[#3[[1]], .1] &)];
bl3 = BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {18.1234, 23.124}}, 5, 
   "LabelingFunction" -> (Round[#3[[1]]] &)];
Row[{bl1, bl2, bl3}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works.

Comment: How does the #3[[1]] part work? I have two plots with log-scaled BarLegend, one from 0.5 to 100, and one from 0.001 to 1000, and I use (NumberForm[#3[[1]], (code..)]&). For the latter, this works, but for the former, I need to replace #3[[1]] with 1.*#3. I am plotting the same type of data, with exactly the same plot functions and options, only the range is different. Where does the difference come from?

Comment: @a20, re "how `#3[[1]]` works", try `BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {18.1234, 23.124}}, 5, 
 "LabelingFunction" -> ((Print[InputForm /@ {##}]; Round[#3[[1]]]) &)]` to see the form of three arguments labeling function takes.  You might want to post the issue in your comment as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_] := x /. {NumberForm[y_, {1, 2}] :> Round[y]}

BarLegend[{"Rainbow", N[ {18, 250}]}, LegendFunction -> f]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have access to legend tick numbers.

Comment: How is that even possible?  Where did your legend get the information that the smallest value was $18.089$ and the largest $248.775$?  As asked:  PLEASE POST YOUR CODE!

Comment: David,  could you try `BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {18.1234, 23.124}}, 5, LegendFunction -> f]`? And, in your example`BarLegend[{"Rainbow", N[ {18, 250}]}]` gives the same result with or without the `LegendFunction->f`.